# Flutter: Notifications do not come when the application is closed

Tags: flutter, push

I am testing an example from https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging/example My code is:

```
FirebaseMessaging messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;

Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);

  await setupFlutterNotifications();
  showFlutterNotification(message);
  print('Handling a background message ${message.messageId}');
}

late AndroidNotificationChannel channel;
bool isFlutterLocalNotificationsInitialized = false;

Future<void> setupFlutterNotifications() async {
  if (isFlutterLocalNotificationsInitialized) {return;}
  channel = const AndroidNotificationChannel(
    'high_importance_channel', // id
    'High Importance Notifications', // title
    description: 'High Importance Notifications', // description
    importance: Importance.high,
  );
  flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()?.createNotificationChannel(channel);

  await FirebaseMessaging.instance.setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(alert: true, badge: true, sound: true,);
  isFlutterLocalNotificationsInitialized = true;
}
void showFlutterNotification(RemoteMessage message) {
  RemoteNotification? notification = message.notification;
  AndroidNotification? android = message.notification?.android;
  if (notification != null && android != null && !kIsWeb) {
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
      notification.hashCode,
      notification.title,
      notification.body,
      NotificationDetails(
        android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
          channel.id,
          channel.name,
          channelDescription: channel.description,
          icon: 'launch_background',
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
late FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin;

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized(); // требуется для PUSH сервиса
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
  await setupFlutterNotifications();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

But for some reason, when the application is closed, PUSH notifications do not come. Although a background process is being created. Nothing is displayed in LogCat either

Update 05.04.2023:

I noticed that when a PUSH notification arrives when the application is running, an error is displayed in the console. Perhaps this is related

```
D/FLTFireMsgReceiver(11337): broadcast received for message
D/Android: [Awesome Notifications](11337): A new Awesome FCM service has started (AwesomeFcmService:46)
D/Android: [Awesome Notifications](11337): received a new fcm push (id: 0:1680679410618292%59af665959af6659) (AwesomeFcmService:134)
E/Android: [Awesome Notifications](11337): Index: 0, Size: 0 (FcmInterpreter:58)
W/System.err(11337): me.carda.awesome_notifications.core.exceptions.AwesomeNotificationsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
W/System.err(11337):    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
W/System.err(11337):    at me.carda.awesome_notifications_fcm.core.builders.FcmNotificationBuilder.getFirstAvailableChannelKey(FcmNotificationBuilder.java:149)
W/System.err(11337):    at me.carda.awesome_notifications_fcm.core.builders.FcmNotificationBuilder.receiveStandardNotificationContent(FcmNotificationBuilder.java:131)
W/System.err(11337):    at me.carda.awesome_notifications_fcm.core.builders.FcmNotificationBuilder.buildNotificationFromExtras(FcmNotificationBuilder.java:79)
W/System.err(11337):    at me.carda.awesome_notifications_fcm.core.interpreters.FcmInterpreter.deliveryAwesomeNotification(FcmInterpreter.java:134)
W/System.err(11337):    at me.carda.awesome_notifications_fcm.core.interpreters.FcmInterpreter.processPushContent(FcmInterpreter.java:100)
W/System.err(11337):    at me.carda.awesome_notifications_fcm.core.interpreters.FcmInterpreter.executeRemoteInstructions(FcmInterpreter.java:79)
W/System.err(11337):    at me.carda.awesome_notifications_fcm.core.services.AwesomeFcmService.passMessageIntentToSdk(AwesomeFcmService.java:174)
W/System.err(11337):    at me.carda.awesome_notifications_fcm.core.services.AwesomeFcmService.handleMessageIntent(AwesomeFcmService.java:137)
W/System.err(11337):    at me.carda.awesome_notifications_fcm.core.services.AwesomeFcmService.handleIntent(AwesomeFcmService.java:70)
W/System.err(11337):    at com.google.firebase.messaging.EnhancedIntentService.lambda$processIntent$0$com-google-firebase-messaging-EnhancedIntentService(EnhancedIntentService.java:78)
W/System.err(11337):    at com.google.firebase.messaging.EnhancedIntentService$$ExternalSyntheticLambda1.run(Unknown Source:6)
W/System.err(11337):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
W/System.err(11337):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
W/System.err(11337):    at com.google.android.gms.common.util.concurrent.zza.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@18.1.0:2)
W/System.err(11337):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize `flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin` before calling the `showFlutterNotification`. You can lazily initialize the `flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin` by moving the initialization code from the `setupFlutterNotifications` method at the start of the main method as shown below:

```
late FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin;

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin(); // initialization code
  await setupFlutterNotifications();
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

Comment: FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin already launched in func setupFlutterNotifications. However, I tried to add it on your advice - it didn 't work